# batch file to create a txt file showing a list of folders inside each subdirectory of a parent folder

Tags: batch-file, directory

I need the correct way to get a simple process to repeat till it reaches end of folder. Inside my Main Folder are multiple subfolders.  Inside each of these are more subfolders along with a few files.

I need to run the batch from inside the Main folder and have it enter each subfolder in turn and simply run "dir *. > %date%.txt", then do the same to the next subfolder till all are done.

The only part I cannot get to work right is the change directory to each in turn till all are done.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
for /f  %%D in ('dir /b /s /ad') do (
    pushd %%D
     dir *. >"%date%.txt"
    popd
)
```

Comment: Close.  But I was not clear enough in what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

to append to a existing file you should use `>>`, try this:

```
cd /d X:\main   &rem put the path to your main folder here
for /r /d %%i in (*) do dir "%%~fi\*.">>"%date%.txt"
```

This reports all subfolder from `X:\main` and there subfolder recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Try these options, if you weren't aware of them:

```
dir "c:\main folder">"%date%.txt"
dir /a-d "c:\main folder">"%date%.txt"
dir /b /s /a-d "c:\main folder">"%date%.txt"
dir /b /s /ad "c:\main folder">"%date%.txt"
```